# Position of the verb "sprechen"

Tags: word-order, standard-german

Which one of the follwiing Bitten (requests) is correct?

1. **Sprechen** Sie bitte langsamer!
2. Bitte **sprechen** Sie langsamer!

I found the first one in a language book. But, I suppose that the second one is correct because the verb, "sprechen" should be at the 2nd position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are correct. Imperative sentences follow the VSO word order, not V2.

And this isn't about the position of the verb *sprechen*, but about the position of the interjection *bitte*. Interjections are tricky to place. They are often placed between subject and object (if any), but you may also have them lead the sentence (a lot of emphasis on *bitte*). Some interjections as *bitte* can also be placed in a main clause of their own and are separated by a comma or full stop (or exclamation/question mark) then.

> Sprechen Sie langsamer!
>
> Sprechen Sie **bitte** langsamer!
>
> **Bitte** sprechen Sie langsamer!
>
> Sprechen Sie langsamer, **bitte**!
>
> Sprechen Sie langsamer! **Bitte**!

---

> Sprechen Sie **aber** nicht lauter!

If there are multiple interjections, the placing becomes more complicated, as they interact with each other:

> Sprechen Sie **aber bitte** den Busfahrer während der Fahrt nicht an!
>
> Sprechen Sie **bitte aber** den Busfahrer während der Fahrt nicht an!
>
> Sprechen Sie den Busfahrer **aber bitte** während der Fahrt nicht an!
>
> Sprechen Sie den Busfahrer **bitte aber** während der Fahrt nicht an!
>
> Sprechen Sie **aber** den Busfahrer **bitte** während der Fahrt nicht an!
>
> Sprechen Sie **bitte** den Busfahrer **aber** während der Fahrt nicht an!

All these are valid, the difference is very subtle. And of course, the ones with leading interjections are also valid, and before *nicht* is another valid place for interjections.

Comment: Are "bitte" and "auch" really interjections??

Comment: In the original sentence as well as the sentences above they transport a mood, so I think: yes. If you only count words as *uff* as interjections, *bitte* and *aber* in the above examples are *Partikel*. Same function as before.